# Can't pass UI controls' values as parameters to method inside Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I'm kind of in a learning process of multi-threading, so while I was playing around with Task class I notice some strange (for me) behavior with calling Task.Factory.StartNew method. I was doing some example in WPF application, where I just tried to call a method from Task on button click and what I have done is this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OrderTickets(numberOfTicktes, cbMovieName.Text));
```

However the method OrderTickets was never called. Then I changed my code like this:

```
string movieName = cbMovies.Text;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OrderTickets(numberOfTicktes, movieName ));
```

After this change my method "OrderTickets" was called as I expected. My question here is why I can not use values of UI controls, like I tried with my combobox, directly inside of Task StartNew method? My guess, this is because UI controls are hold by the UI thread but not quite sure about it. Can anyone explain to me what really happens here? Could you point me to Microsoft documentation describing this?

Comment: I am not sure but `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OrderTickets(numberOfTicktes, cbMovieName.Text))` this has to work right ?

Comment: Well that's what I thought but when I try to do it that way, the method OrderTickets is just never invoked. Then after I moved that to separate variable, it works as it is expected.

Comment: second code snippet would have created closure on variable movieName and should have worked. whereas in 1st case not sure if something would have gone wrong while thread accessing UI control text property

Comment: @Stojdza : din't you get any error while executing first code snippet ?

Comment: It's a good question. While you can easily google other StackOverflow questions/answers that WPF doesn't allow read access from other than UI threads on controls, and that WPF is silent about that, I couldn't find any info on MSDN. Could you possibly rephrase your question, so it asks for a link to a Microsoft documentation? It would be interresting.

Comment: @Rahul Agarwal No I did not get any errors for calling it like that. But can't be 100% sure because possibly I did not handle them correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access WPF controls from a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629591/how-to-access-wpf-controls-from-a-background-thread)

Comment: @Stojdza : Maciek comment looks to be explaining mystery when he says _WPF is silent about that_ and why it worked in second case i already answered

Comment: Here is a link on WPF not throwing errors when accessing from other threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/710082/275330

Comment: As an aside, you probably want [to avoid StartNew](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) anyway.

Comment: Yes but I would be expecting some kind of exception to be thrown in this case. Just like if i tried to access the UI control inside the OrderTickets method, without using Dispatcher.

Comment: Not the second case, but the first one. Where i tried to pass the value to method by directly accessing combobox.Text property. Second case works as expected.

Comment: @MaciekŚ. " Could you possibly rephrase your question, so it asks for a link to a Microsoft documentation?" sorry I'm not quite sure how to rephrase it :D. Any help? And thanks for response.

Comment: No - there are no exceptions on write access from other threads (except for when a class strictly forbids it like an ObservableCollection). And this can work in 99.99% cases until for one user it doesn't, and you refactor an app to use Dispatcher everywhere :)

Comment: @Stojdza - like: "Can anyone explain to me what really happens here?
 Could you point me to Microsoft documentation describing this?"

Comment: @mjwills Actually it helps. There is indeed exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.". I was able to catch it in ContinueWith method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't immediately obvious, but the issue is that you are running into **two** issues - and they way they interact is a bit confusing.

**Issue 1** - you can't access controls outside of the [UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model).

**Issue 2** - StartNew doesn't [bubble up exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883850/catching-error-when-using-task-factory) in the way you are expecting it to. `ContinueWith` may assist with this.

*The net result is it **looks** to you like the call failed without throwing an exception.*

Answer (score 2):

If your code could speak, this is what you are doing:

"I am the main thread. Hey scheduler can you please do this work for me using a thread from the pool?"

```
() => OrderTickets(numberOfTicktes, cbMovieName.Text)
```

Main thread is now free and sometime later (or immediately) a pool thread picks up this work to do it and notices this:

```
cbMovieName.Text
```

So it tries to communicate with `cbMovieName` but the thread (in your case main thread or UI thread) intervenes and says:

"Hey pool thread, why are you trying to communicate with one of my controls without asking me? Go away!!! (As he rolls his eyes)"

Exception is thrown on the pool thread but not bubbled up. Therefore, it seems to you like it was never called but all the above happened.

In the other case where you have this:

```
string movieName = cbMovies.Text;
() => OrderTickets(numberOfTicktes, movieName)
```

It will work because the pool thread does not need any UI control.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! It's really helpful for understanding how something works, when you put it simple like that. My guess was accurate but didn't have a clue what was going on under the hood. Great one!